# How to query for isinactive item using Netsuite REST API

Tags: netsuite

I have what must be a simple question, but I've scoured the documentation and web and can't seem to find an answer.

Is there a way to query on isinactive when querying for items via the Netsuite API?

In my RESTlet when I try to specify "isinactive" with new nlobjSearchColumn() I get an error saying "undefined".

When I add a filter via new nlobjSearchFilter('isinactive', null, 'is', 0) it doesn't give me an error, it simply ignores the condition.

All I really want to accomplish is to query for active records only along with all of my other search criteria.

Comment: `isinactive` is a checkbox field, so it's values will be `'T'` or `'F'`, so your filter on a value of `0` will not affect your search either way.

What exactly is `undefined`? Can you give more of your code?

Comment: isianctive can be both a search filter and a search column. like @egrubaugh360 said you need to use 'T' or 'F' for filtering, and also can you share your code snippet for saved search, the undefined error looks more like a javascript error

Comment: Ugh.  I'm so embarassed.  I tried 0 and false, but not F.  Duh.  Thanks for the  help.